# webpack bundle size is larger than it should be

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I have an existing Laravel app and for part of the app, I'm using Laravel Mix. I have 6 single file components with the CSS inside the Vue file. My largest Vue file is 41KB, but the rest are 10-17kb each.

I'm using Laravel Mix to bundle the js inside webpack.mix.js : `mix .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'dist/js')`. My development app size is 767kb and my production bundle size is 265kb. Im trying to reduce the production app size, since it's just handling my vue files (js/CSS) so I'm not sure why it's so large.

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true, 
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js", 
        "watch": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js", 
        "hot": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js", 
        "production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    }, 
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0", 
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7", 
        "jquery": "^3.1.0", 
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.14", 
        "lodash": "^4.16.2", 
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1", 
        "sass": "^1.17.2", 
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0", 
        "vue": "^2.6.10", 
        "vue-loader": "^15.7.0", 
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10", 
        "webpack": "^4.29.6"
    }, 
    "dependencies": { }
}
```

Do you have any ideas? 260kb feels like a lot for this.

Comment: You may want to add your mix config file too.  Did you split external, vendor, and app or did you bundle everything including vue, jquery, and lodash?  It can also depend on how you import the modules, i.e: lodash modules can be individually import, example: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark

Comment: Have you tried moving some of the libraries such as jQuery, lodash, etc to `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`? `devDependencies` is for build tools like Webpack and sass-loader. Although I can't find any docs that explain whether that affects bundle size.